# What are mag_a, mag_i, mag_z, a*, and sin_i * from the SDSS Moving Objects Data?

Tags: data-analysis, sloan-dss

I'm currently working on the SDSS Moving Objects data sets and came across the column names mag_a, mag_i, mag_z, aprime, and sin_iprime. Can someone describe what these attributes mean, or where I can read more about them?

Comment: Can you add a link to where you are seeing these columns? Looking at the table on [SDSS MOC 4 catalog](http://faculty.washington.edu/ivezic/sdssmoc/sdssmoc.html) page shows some similar names but not exactly. `mag_i/z` could be the _i_ and _z_ band magnitudes, and `aprime` and `sin_iprime` could correspond to those under the 'proper elements' section (long-term stable elements, intended for family identification)